# In App Purchases status Ready to submit after submitting application to Appstore

Tags: app-store, in-app-purchase

I Have developed a Non-Consumable In-App Purchase iOS Application.. I have taken bundle identifiers for In-App Purchases, And wrote the code and submitted to appstore... After submitting the application, The status it is showing at the In-App Purchases is "Ready to submit" at the column of "Manage In-App Purchases" field in the submitted application.. How to submit In-App Purchase Applications... Is there any need to submit a free application first after that In-App Purchase Application..?

Answer (score 0):

1. Submit application (my by fake code)
2. Reject application (for test abilityes)
3. Submit in-app purchase
4. The in app purchase can be tested.
5. Submit right application code.